# EF error when generating database: The custom database generation workflow file references the assembly 'EntityFramework'

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5, visual-studio-2013

I made some changed to my .edmx and I am trying to generate a database from the model and a window opens that has this error:

> The custom database generation workflow file references the assembly
>   'EntityFramework' that exists in the owning project, but could not be
>   loaded due to the following exception: 'Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.'.

Any ideas?

Edit: This appears to be a Visual Studio 2013 preview related problem. I opened the project in VS2012 and I do not have this problem.

Any help in solving this issue would still be appreciated, however.